# getting the id of popoverd element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

here is my popover code:

```
$(function () {
  $('.popover').popover({ 
    html : true,
    content: console.log($(this).id) ,
    placement:  'top'
  });
});
```

and here is my html code:

```
<a class="popover" id="CHANGING-NUMBER(4,5,6,....)"> Foo </a>
```

but the output shown in the console just shows "undefined". How can I get the id of the anchor which shows the popover?

Comment: you are not actually setting content btw, as console.log does not return anything.

Comment: are you using bootstrap? or another popover plugin?

Comment: @PatrickEvans, here I have nothing to do with the content and nope, the console shows its log( I used console.log because if I used `content:$(this).id` I would not get the exact error or detail.

Comment: @koala_dev, I'm using bootstrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At that point `this` doesn't refer to the element. You need to pass the id to each element individually:

```
$(function () {  
  $('.popover').each( function() {
    $(this).popover({ 
        html : true,
        content: this.id,
        placement: 'top'
    });
  });
});
```